# LSTM prediction shift(-1) or not

Tags: lstm

I am new to LSTM and I want to ask how th prediction works when you have multivariable problem. In my case I have 100 variables that I think have a prediction capability to the target variable. In my case, it is a binary (0,1). My question is do I have to shift the target variable up meaning do I have to do shift(-1) before training the model.In my problem I am feeding the model 100 technical indicators to predict if the price is going up 1 or zero. I am asking about the shift becuase if I dont shift than there is no prediction aka future.

I would really appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I shift my target column before prediction. If you don't shift you aren't predicting the next time step. I never see this mentioned for some reason.

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/65108/should-i-shift-a-dataset-to-use-it-for-time-series-regression-with-rnn-lstm

```
df[self.temp_column] = df[self.target_column].shift(-self.forecast_steps)
       
df = df.dropna(subset=[self.temp_column])
```